# esp32 with external antenna not flashing

Tags: esp32, esp-idf

I just bought a ESP32-WROOM-32U and can not get it to Flash Mode.
I own severall ESP32 Node MCU s and they all Flash with no issues. Just plug in and click flash in the esp-idf addon of vs code.

But now I got this device with the external wifi antenna and it is just not working. Tryed severall cables, tryed different computers and esp-idf versions. Tryed several combinations of clicking EN and Boot button or do nothing of it. Tryed with or without antenna.

It is just not working. If I plug it in I can see a WLAN but cannot connect to a webserver or something.

Can anyone tell me what I can do to get it flashing.

Regards Manuel